# Undefined index after loadMoreRows is called

Tags: react-virtualized

I have the following example implementing the `InfiniteLoader` with a `Table` which is setting the `Table` `rowCount` to a known large number (count of logs in the db) and the `InfiniteLoader` `rowCount` to the size of the batch of logs I fetch. I need this so that the user knows how much data there is based on the scroll heigth. Otherwise, he would have to scroll to the end and see if more logs are loaded. Could be that I'm misusing the two `rowCount` props, but whenever I scroll fast to an index close to the end, where data is not loaded yet, `data` is undefined in the `getRowClassName` function. I assumed the `loadMoreRows` would get called in this case.

```
import React = require('react');
import _ = require('lodash');
import Immutable = require('immutable');
import Api = require('./Api');

const STATUS_LOADING = 1,
      STATUS_LOADED = 2,
      LOG_LIMIT = 200;

interface Props {
    logEntries: Immutable.List<Immutable.Map<string, any>>;
}

interface State {
    logEntries?: Immutable.List<Immutable.Map<string, any>>;
    count?: number;
    loadedRowsMap?: any;
}

class LogViewer extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            logEntries: props.logEntries,
            count: 0,
            loadedRowsMap: {}
        };
    }

    render() {
        return {this.renderLoader()};
    }

    private renderLoader() {
        const {logEntries, count} = this.state;
        return (
            <InfiniteLoader isRowLoaded={this.isRowLoaded.bind(this)}
                            loadMoreRows={this.loadMoreRows.bind(this)}
                            minimumBatchSize={LOG_LIMIT}
                            rowCount={logEntries.size} >
                {
                    ({onRowsRendered, registerChild}) => (
                        <AutoSizer disableHeight>
                            {
                                ({width}) => (
                                    <Table headerHeight={20}
                                           height={400}
                                           onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                                           ref={registerChild}
                                           rowCount={count}
                                           className='log-entries'
                                           gridClassName='grid'
                                           rowClassName={this.getRowClassName.bind(this)}
                                           headerStyle={{ fontSize: 15 }}
                                           rowGetter={({index}) => logEntries.get(index)}
                                           rowHeight={50}
                                           width={width} >
                                        <Column label='Name'
                                                key='name'
                                                dataKey='name'
                                                width={200} />
                                    </Table>
                                )
                            }
                        </AutoSizer>
                    )
                }
            </InfiniteLoader>
        );
    }

    private getRowClassName({index}) {
        const {logEntries} = this.state;
        if(index > -1) {
            const data = logEntries.get(index);
            return `log-entry ${data.get('name').toLowerCase()}`;
        }

        return '';
    }

    private isRowLoaded({index}) {
        const {loadedRowsMap} = this.state;
        return !!loadedRowsMap[index];
    }

    private loadMoreRows({startIndex, stopIndex}) {
        const {loadedRowsMap, level, logEntries} = this.state;

        _.range(startIndex, stopIndex).forEach(i => {
            loadedRowsMap[i] = STATUS_LOADING;
        });
        this.setState({ loadedRowsMap });

        const offset = Math.floor((startIndex + 1) / LOG_LIMIT);
        return Api.logs(LOG_LIMIT, offset)
            .then(({body: [count, logs]}) => {
                _.range(startIndex, stopIndex).forEach(i => {
                    loadedRowsMap[i] = STATUS_LOADED;
                });
                const newLogs = logEntries.toJS().concat(logs);
                this.setState({
                    count,
                    logEntries: Immutable.fromJS(newLogs)
                });
            });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could be that I'm misusing the two `rowCount` props

You should pass the same `rowCount` value to both `InfiniteLoader` and `Table`. It should either be the total size of all of your data on the server (as shown [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/InfiniteLoader.md#examples)) or the size of your local data +1 to allow loading more when a user scrolls near the end (as shown [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/creatingAnInfiniteLoadingList.md)).

> whenever I scroll fast to an index close to the end, where data is not loaded yet, data is undefined in the `getRowClassName` function. I assumed the `loadMoreRows` would get called in this case.

`loadMoreRows` does get called- but it's async. react-virtualized won't block user scrolling until data loads. Your `getRowClassName` function needs to handle the fact that a user may scroll faster than your lazy-loaded data is able to load. You can show a different "load in progress" UI for unloaded rows if you'd like.

Comment: So, the way I'm using the 2 `rowCount`s is correct?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part of your question. Edited my answer to include some more detail.

Comment: On the first link you provided with the total count, it doesn't actually use the same count. The `InfiniteLoader` uses an undefined `remoteRowCount` while the `Table` uses the `list.length`

Comment: Also, when you said that I can show a loading UI, you mean override the default `rowRenderer` function?

Comment: That's a typo. They should both use `remoteRowCount` in that example. (I'll update the docs.) Loading UI just means... display something differently if the data hasn't yet loaded, as is shown in the 2nd example.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!